# Magento cache concept store custom block or custom model object data

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, model, custom

I do not understand properly cache concept in magento.

I want to store data in cache so when user again refer data/page ,it automatically get from cache that data rather than fire server request.When data changed from backend then it should go for request to server.How can I 
Handle this from cache.
I have code but how can I use this code.

```
 Mage::app()->saveCache($data, $this->_cacheId, array(self::CACHE_TAG), 604800);
```

How fetch backend custom model data from backend using cache support ?. My model is `Mage::getModel('testimonial/data')->getCollection()` how can I use this model data as cache data ? OR how can fetch fast bulk custom model data ?somone understand to me ?